Get data sleep duration from goole fite with Fitness API
`How do I calculate the duration of sleep I get from Google Fit.
this is an example of json from google fit the code
"session": [
    {
        "id": "healthkit-0B3E9A38-694F-4B88-B15B-9C534759131D",
        "name": "Tidur",
        "description": "",
        "startTimeMillis": "1713798000000",
        "endTimeMillis": "1713817920000",
        "modifiedTimeMillis": "1713826670476",
        "application": {
            "packageName": "com.xiaomi.miwatch.pro",
            "version": "",
            "detailsUrl": ""
        },
        "activityType": 72
    },
    {
        "id": "healthkit-ABA36AB8-09E5-4AEC-9A6B-AA9DC5547567",
        "name": "Tidur",
        "description": "",
        "startTimeMillis": "1713798000000",
        "endTimeMillis": "1713817920000",
        "modifiedTimeMillis": "1713826670476",
        "application": {
            "packageName": "com.xiaomi.miwatch.pro",
            "version": "",
            "detailsUrl": ""
        },
        "activityType": 72
    },
    {
        "id": "healthkit-E5E08251-357B-4620-B0AB-6EDC0321F8BB",
        "name": "Tidur",
        "description": "",
        "startTimeMillis": "1713798000000",
        "endTimeMillis": "1713817920000",
        "modifiedTimeMillis": "1713826670476",
        "application": {
            "packageName": "com.xiaomi.miwatch.pro",
            "version": "",
            "detailsUrl": ""
        },
        "activityType": 72
    }
],
"deletedSession": []

'

What does that data mean? What have you tried to do with it?

The meaning of this data is:
startTimeMillis: start time of the activity
endTImeMillis: the end of the activity time
ActivityType: sleep

well, it's just a matter of iterating through the session array - adding up the difference between startTimeMillis and endTimeMillis

assuming the data is in a variable called data, that would be simply data.session.filter(({activityType})=>activityType===72).reduce((acc,{startTimeMillis,endTimeMillis})=>endTimeMillis-startTimeMillis+acc,0);

const data = {
"session": [
const totalDurasiTidurMillis = data.session
.filter(({ id }) => id === "healthkit-0B3E9A38-694F-4B88-B15B-9C534759131D" ||
id === "healthkit-ABA36AB8-09E5-4AEC-9A6B-AA9DC5547567" ||
.reduce((acc, { startTimeMillis, endTimeMillis }) => {
return acc + (parseInt(endTimeMillis) - parseInt(startTimeMillis));
}, 0);
const totalDurasiTidurJam = totalDurasiTidurMillis / (1000 * 60 * 60);
console.log(Total durasi tidur: ${totalDurasiTidurJam} jam);

this doesn't work,
I code me,
and the result is 16 hours, the actual google fit application is 6 hours 22 minutes

the actual times in your data are 3 times 5 hours and 32 minutes, total 16 hours 36 minutes ... sure, the times are the same, but that's the data you posted -, anyway, how do you figure that it should be 6 hours 22 minutes? From some other data?

The json data is data that I took from Google Fit using the Rest API.
I still haven't found an algorithm for how to decode that data

well, the data shows the same 5:32 period 3 times ... so, not sure where you even get 6:22

Can I contact you via direct message, I want to offer you a project

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
